# Magento 2 : Reset filters in a collection such as addFieldtoFilter, addAttribute to filter etc

Tags: magento2, collection, product-collection

I want to deploy following logic ;

```
 - Load product collection

  *start loop*


 - Extract the value with which I filter collection.



 - Filter based on above attribute to see if the product is there.



 - Reset the collection so I can use the same collection for filtering
   again


    *end loop*
```

But I do not know how to reset filters in a collection such as addFieldtoFilter, addAttribute to filter etc.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use clone 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php

```
$_collection = $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection();
$collection = clone $_collection;
// your action here $collection->load() ->addFieldtoFilter etc.
foreach($collection as $product) {
 // do something
}
```

$_collection - is not change

Comment: best solution I have got +1.. Thanks man :)